# how to save awk result from hadoop to a variable in shell script?

Tags: hadoop, sh

I am trying to save filter result from hadoop using awk into a variable in sh script but I failed :
when I run this in the shell comand I get this result  :

```
 hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ngdaas/FlareData/output_8/CustomerSubject/aggr=daily/tbl_dt=20180623 | awk '{print $6,$7}'

2018-07-03 06:18
```

now I try to save this result (
    2018-07-03 06:18) into sh variable I try to write :

```
  #!/bin/bash
    load_date="hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ngdaas/FlareData/output_8/CustomerSubject/aggr=daily/tbl_dt=${today} | awk '{print $6,$7}'"
    echo "${load_date}"
```

But it did not work it print the same comand not the result of command , any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$` to store a shell variable, though I haven't tested it since I don't have hadoop with me.

```
load_date=$(hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ngdaas/FlareData/output_8/CustomerSubject/aggr=daily/tbl_dt=${today} | awk '{print $6,$7}')
```